# MySQL Using Explain to optimize queries from execution plan

Tags: mysql

I have a select query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT distinct col1 FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 b USING (col1) 
WHERE b.col2='XXX'
```

table1 is a table that is 1.8 million records, while table2 has 20 million records. The distinct number of col1 records in table1 is ~100K. When I do an **Explain** on the query:

1. table1 has 1.8m records with 100.00 filtered, and Using index; Using temporary in the Extra column
2. table2 has 5.00 in the filtered column, and Using Where; Distinct in the Extra column

Is it correct to say that MySQL first queries out the entire 1.8 million records, before filtering it down or am I interpreting the results of Explain wrongly? If so, is there a way to force the filtering to be done on table1 first, i.e. getting filtered on step 1 down to 100K/1.8M percent so that I can avoid "using temporary" if the buffer becomes full?

**Table Schema**
col1: Primary Key for table2 | col2: No indexes | col1 + col3: Primary Key for table1

**Execution Plan**

id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra

1   SIMPLE  table1      index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 27      1815838 100.00  Using index; Using temporary

1   SIMPLE  table2      eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 24  table1.col1 1   5.00    Using where; Distinct

Comment: please show table schemas and execution plan

Comment: I think the assumption is (quite reasonably) that table1.col1 is a surrogate PK. If that's not the case then you need to be explicit about that. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear earlier (kind of missed out some details), the primary key for table1 is a composite between two columns, col1 and col3. For table2, the primary key is col1. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking it through and thinking very hard over the execution path, I realized I overlooked one thing. Reversing the order of the tables in the query solved the issue for me. Posting this in case anyone else runs into the same issue as I did. The performance gain over here is a big win from the original query.

```
SELECT col1 FROM table2
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table1) 
AND col2='XXX'
```

**Revised Execution Plan**

id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra

1 SIMPLE table2 index PRIMARY PRIMARY 27 1815838 7.12 Using index; LooseScan

1 SIMPLE table1 eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 24 table1.col1 1 5.00 Using where; Distinct